# How to perform batch jobs after Elastic Beanstalk deployment unzipping uploaded file

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment, setup-deployment

I need to make some files executable after AWS elastic-beanstalk unzip my uploaded zipped file. I need elastic-beanstalk automatically do chmod before the application can work properly such as:

```
sudo chmod 755  /var/www/html/mybin/executablefile1  
sudo chmod 755  /var/www/html/mybin/executablefile2
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the commands you want to execute (including chmod) in [container_commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) section of your [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html):

> Container commands **run after the application and web server have been set up** and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

Alternatively, you can also use one of [deployment platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). For example your custom script in `postdeploy`:

> Files here run after the Elastic Beanstalk platform engine deploys the application and proxy server. This is the **last deployment workflow** step.